# Replicated Ehcache not working

Tags: java, ehcache

I am trying to enable replecated ehcache and for some reason it does not seem to be working.

My ehcache.xml -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
         updateCheck="true" monitoring="autodetect"
         dynamicConfig="true"> 

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/> 

    <transactionManagerLookup class="net.sf.ehcache.transaction.manager.DefaultTransactionManagerLookup"
                              properties="jndiName=java:/TransactionManager" propertySeparator=";"/> 
    <cacheManagerEventListenerFactory class="com.adobe_services.cache.SampleCacheManagerEventListenerFactory" properties="type=counting"/>
  <cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
            class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
            properties="peerDiscovery=automatic,
                        multicastGroupAddress=230.0.0.1,
                        multicastGroupPort=4446, timeToLive=1"
            propertySeparator=","
            />
    <cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
                                     properties="hostName=, port=, socketTimeoutMillis="/> 
     <defaultCache
            maxElementsInMemory="10000"
            eternal="false"
            timeToIdleSeconds="120"
            timeToLiveSeconds="120"
            overflowToDisk="true"
            diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="30"
            maxElementsOnDisk="10000000"
            diskPersistent="false"
            diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
            memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
            statistics="false"
            />

    <cache name="replicatedCache"
    maxElementsInMemory="5"
           maxElementsOnDisk="100000"
           eternal="true"
           overflowToDisk="true"
           diskPersistent="true"
           diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
           timeToIdleSeconds="3600"
           timeToLiveSeconds="3600"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
           transactionalMode="off">
        <cacheEventListenerFactory
                class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"/>
        <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory"
        properties="bootstrapAsynchronously=false, maximumChunkSizeBytes=5000000"
        propertySeparator="," />
    </cache>   

</ehcache>
```

When i insert a value in one cache and then extract it in another clustered instance i am not able to get the object. I am using tomcat clustering on the same machine.

Not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice your cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory properties are blank, i.e. `properties="hostName=, port=, socketTimeoutMillis="`.

Try filling them out with the appropriate server instance settings and see if that works. This situation noted [here](https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALFCOM-3011) may be similar to what you are experiencing.

Answer (score -1):

If you are testing EhCache locally, try:

```
multicastGroupAddress=127.0.0.1
```

But when you will switch to true network environment, use `230.0.0.1` again. I assume `230.0.0.1` is your primary network interface broadcast address as returned by `ifconfig` `Bcast` value.

Comment: I am getting this error - "java.net.SocketException: Not a multicast address" if i try to set 127.0.0.1 as multicast address